# Python object identification for many to one relationships

Tags: python

I'm working on a project and I'm stuck with a problem where the instance of one a class is passed to many workers objects.

```
broker = Broker(...)

worker1 = Worker(broker, "001")
worker2 = Worker(broker, "002")
worker3 = Worker(broker, "003")
```

All these workers are now calling functions from the Broker object they got passed as an argument. As the workers are all managing different Broker-accounts which are identified by an ID, the `id` arguments ("001", "002", "003") need to be passed from the workers to the broker on each function call so that they can identify themselves and the Broker knows onto which Account he has to sent the instructions.

An action that resolves out of the internal algorithmic logic could be to close all positions for worker1:

```
worker1.closeAllPositions()
```

The functional implementation for the Worker-Class is done in such a way that the instruction is passed to the Broker-Class. But as the Broker does need to know the ID of the worker currently calling it, its `id` is passed as an argument:

```
class Worker:

    def __init__(self, broker, id):
         self.id = id
         self.broker = broker

    def closeAllPositions(self):
        self.broker.closeAllPositions(self.id)

    def getSummary(self):
        self.broker.getSummary(self.id)

    def getBalance(self):
        self.broker.getBalance(self.id)
```

All Broker interfaces are now equipped with the `id` parameter, so that any function call from a worker to the Broker is identified with an account. But as the Broker functions have sub-dependencies (id passed to first who no has to pass the id to any further broker function in the chain) the `id`-problem gets out of control and ID's are passed everywhere quickly which looks very unclean to me.

```
class Broker:

   def __init__(self, ...):
        ...

    def getSummary(self, id):
        self.setCallerID(id)                    <-!!! Ugly
        ....

    def getBalance(self, id, returnType):
        self.setCallerID(id)                    <-!!! Ugly
        ....
```

Instead of passing this information on any function call I'm looking for an *under the hood* method to resolve the callers ID. Something like a hook being invoked to set the caller ID, that runs whenever a Broker method is called.

**The order in which Workers call Broker functions and which Worker functions is not determinable and the order in which Workers want to interact with the single broker is completely random.**

**-> Therefore any call onto the Worker-Broker-interface needs some kind of identifier.**

Is there an elegant way in Python how an object can identify itself towards an other object without passing an ID parameter with any function call?

Comment: Pass the worker object itself?

Comment: @AndrasDeak You mean instead of passing the Broker to the workers, pass all the workers to the Broker?

Comment: I mean passing `self` when calling broker methods from a worker, so the broker knows which worker called it. Perhaps I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could give your `Worker` objects methods that call the appropriate `Broker` methods with their `id`s

```
class Worker
    def __init__(self, broker, id):
        self.broker = broker
        self.id = id

    def closeAllPositions(self):
        return self.broker.closeAllPositions(self.id)
```

Then instead of `self.broker.closeAllPositions("id")`, you would just invoke  `self.closeAllPositions()` instead